# NullPointerException at openFileOutput in Activity

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I have an Activity with an ImageView, which, if it is empty and clicked, should load an image from Internet and save it to internal storage. So the activity looks like this:

```
public class PlaceCreate extends Activity {
Context context;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.create);
  context = this;

  ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
  img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        EditText edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
        Download(edit.getText().toString());
    }
  });
}

private boolean Download(String Name)
{
  try
  {
    URL u = new URL("http://example.com/img.png");
    HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection)u.openConnection();
    c.setRequestMethod("GET");
    c.setDoOutput(true);
    c.connect();
    FileOutputStream f = context.openFileOutput(Name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    InputStream in = c.getInputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int len1 = 0;
    while((len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0 )
    {
      f.write(buffer, 0, len1);
    }
    f.close();

    FileInputStream is = openFileInput(Name);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    is.close();
    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewPlan);
    img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
  }
  catch(IOException e)
  {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}}
```

The problem is that I get NullPointerException on the line with `openFileOutput`. I found a couple of similar questions, but all answers imply that `null` is a missing context. As it's an activity in this case, it obviously has a context (`this`), and it is not null. I tried to call `openFileOutput` (with `this` implied) and via the `context` member. Either approach fails. Also I tried to pass `v.getContext()` from `onClick` into `Download` as an additional parameter, and this value was not null, yet produced the same exception as well. (If it is important, the name of the file requested is a valid filename, for example "abc".)

Could someone shed some light on this?

Here is an example of the stack:

```
04-22 00:45:10.659: W/dalvikvm(330): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
04-22 00:45:10.909: E/AndroidRuntime(330): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-22 00:45:10.909: E/AndroidRuntime(330): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-22 00:45:10.909: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.ContextImpl.openFileOutput(ContextImpl.java:420)
04-22 00:45:10.909: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileOutput(ContextWrapper.java:158)
04-22 00:45:10.909: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at com.example.scanner.PlaceCreate.Download(PlaceCreate.java:93)
04-22 00:45:10.909: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at com.example.scanner.PlaceCreate.access$0(PlaceCreate.java:84)
04-22 00:45:10.909: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at com.example.scanner.PlaceCreate$3.onClick(PlaceCreate.java:67)
04-22 00:45:10.909: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
04-22 00:45:10.909: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
04-22 00:45:10.909: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-22 00:45:10.909: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-22 00:45:10.909: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-22 00:45:10.909: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-22 00:45:10.909: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-22 00:45:10.909: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-22 00:45:10.909: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-22 00:45:10.909: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-22 00:45:10.909: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And here is some more findings. According to the stack, the error occures inside `ContextImpl` file, and I see that `parent` local variable is null inside this method. Here is the code:

```
public FileOutputStream openFileOutput(String name, int mode)
  throws FileNotFoundException {
  final boolean append = (mode&MODE_APPEND) != 0;
  File f = makeFilename(getFilesDir(), name);
  try {
     FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f, append);
     setFilePermissionsFromMode(f.getPath(), mode, 0);
     return fos;
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
 }

 File parent = f.getParentFile();
 parent.mkdir();
 FileUtils.setPermissions(
     parent.getPath(),
     FileUtils.S_IRWXU|FileUtils.S_IRWXG|FileUtils.S_IXOTH,
     -1, -1);
 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f, append);
 setFilePermissionsFromMode(f.getPath(), mode, 0);
 return fos;
}
```

So now the question is how can I make sure that the call to `f.getParentFile()` will not return null, and why does it work from time to time?

Comment: When you say ...the name is a valid filename, for example "abc", is that an actual filename you have tried?

Comment: Please provide the complete stack trace.

Comment: @MisterSquonk: Yes, I tried 'abc' as well. What is wrong with this name?

Comment: @CommonsWare: Strangely, but after reboot I can't get the exception, the code works. Sorry for asking a question, which seems having no ground in the code.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Well, it's back again, here is the stack:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is proved to be a feature of Android 2.3.3 emulator installed here as a part of SDK. The problem does not occur if I use a real device with Android 2.3.3. Also the code works ok if I use Android 4.0.3 emulator. So, if some weird things happen, tests in another environment can shed some light. I hope this can help someone else in similar problem solving.

Comment: @d34th4ck3r, no, it's not clear which product is affected and/or which environment settings cause the problem. Also, I'd like to get some confirmation of the problem from other people at first.

Comment: You can count me in the confirmation.

Comment: @d34th4ck3r, the problem is that it's about old SDK version, and seems not affecting newer version, so it should be treated as fixed, imho.

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is that I get NullPointerException on the line with openFileOutput.

You are getting a `NullPointerException` inside the *implementation* of `openFileOutput()`. This is why you need to supply SO with a stack trace, rather than just supplying exception names. An exception *on* a line is different than an exception *triggered by* a line, particularly with `NullPointerException`.

Based on my reading of `openFileOutput()` on [`ContextImpl`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java), either:

- `Name` is `null`, or
- you have an exceedingly strange `context`, or
- there is some other possible problem on the version of Android you are running that is not visible in the current implementation of `openFileOutput()`

I would start by deleting `context` entirely, as you are inside an `Activity` and do not need it. Then, put in some `Log` statements or set breakpoints to see what `Name` is.

Comment: Did you see new version of the question with the stack and new findings? The line with `f.getParentFile()` in the `ContextImpl`  produces `null`.

Comment: @Stan: When `f.getParentFile()` returns `null`, what does `f` contain?

Comment: f File  (id=830007877600) 
 absolutePath "/a" (id=830007877752) 
 path "a" (id=830007877784) parent null, meaning that I chose the name `a` for this time.

Comment: @Stan: What did you type into the `EditText` to generate this result? If the answer is `/a`, there's your problem -- `openFileInput()` and `openFileOutput()` only work with bare filenames, sans any paths.

Comment: No, I typed `a`, of course. If I type `/a` (which I tried because I already just don't know what to do) I get another exception.

Comment: @Stan: That means `getFilesDir()` returned `null` when `f` was created, and I have no explanation for that. Try creating a separate sample project that reproduces the error. If you can, upload it somewhere and I'll take a peek at it. If you cannot create a separate sample that has the same effect, then figure out what is different between the new sample and your existing code.

Comment: Ok, I'll do it (hope I'll manage to catch the exception in a simple project). Just in case, this happens under emulator with Android 2.3.3 platform. I'm trying on 4-th now.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem on my Asus TF101 running ICS - i.e. a real device rather than an emulator. It was vexing since it turned out that the problem was related to the Linux write permissions on the underlying folder.

I had been playing with using shared resources with the `android:sharedUserId` tag in my manifest file. Since the UID had changed, the activity no longer had write permission in the data files directory.

so anything that might change the uid will potentially cause this problem.

To solve the problem I:

1. Removed the `sharedUserID` tag from the manifest (possibly optional);
2. Manually uninstalled the app from my device.
3. Re-installed the app.

It then ran perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

By reading the code for openFileOutput() I can see one case where f.getParentFile() may return null that has not been mentioned in any other answer or comment here.

In the line

```
File f = makeFilename(getFilesDir(), name);
```

[getFilesDir()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/android/app/ContextImpl.java#ContextImpl.getFilesDir%28%29) can return null if the [dataDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html#dataDir) does not exist and if  `getFilesDir()` fails to create the dataDir. If this happens the file `f` will only have a parent if the `name` is a path (such as "directory/file") and not just a file (such as "file").

I do not know under which circumstances the dataDir would be missing and when it would be impossible to create it, but it doesn't sound unlikely that it for some reason can't be created in the Android 2.3.3 Emulator.

Answer (score 0):

see [this](http://android-example-code.blogspot.in/p/download-store-and-read-images-from.html) complete example

```
URL url = new URL (strURL);
input = url.openStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1500];
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream ("/sdcard/abc.png");
int bytesRead = 0;
while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) >= 0) .
{
 output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't need external storage (such as sd card), I need internal storage. In examples for this case I saw, that single filename (without a path) is ok.